# Getting and Setting position of Content with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `table` with two rows, the first being the `thead` the second being the `tbody` (yes I know I have not included these tags, no need to correct). My goal here is to get the position of each `th`. My overall all goal is to clone the content of each `th` and prepend it to each corresponding `td`, so I have a very mobile friendly table, except I do not know how to achieve this dynamically.

```
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
</tr>
```

I'm just confused on how I could get the position of each `th`, I think once I have that, I can solve the rest of this problem. Can anyone give me a hint of where I should be going with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you want this output:

```
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1 - one</td>
    <td>2 - two</td>
    <td>3 - three</td>
    <td>4 - four</td>
</tr>
```

If so you need to use `index()` to get the column of the `th` and append as required. Try this:

```
$('tr td').each(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $(this).prepend($('th').eq(idx).text() + ' - ');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ8eP/)

Comment: Very close to what I was looking for, nothing I can't work form, thank you very much for your time!